# Item display page is not working properly when click on view details button within boostrap tab

Tags: html, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am facing a problem  to dispaly product details page. I have four boostrap tab and in these tab has some **Product Item** with a **Quick View** "link Button.Every product should be display properly with the unique id when click on link button .But it's not working as I expected.I am using foreach loop and passing product id for every product,when click event is occurring all four tab items having same id are  displayed .It should be displayed only one item.

I've tried lots of different solution .what should I do with foreach loop and Id. 
Any help would would be greatly appreaciated.
Following are the more details about the my application

```html
<!--This is my Single.cshtml page-->
@foreach (var item in Model.ProductList)
        {
            <div class="col-md-4 single-right-left ">

                <div class="grid images_3_of_2">

                    <div class="flexslider">


                        <ul class="slides">

                            <li data-thumb="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageaFront)">
                                <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageaFront)" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive"> </div>
                            </li>
                            <li data-thumb="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageBack)">
                                <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageBack)" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive"> </div>
                            </li>
                            <li data-thumb="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageBack)">
                                <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageBack)" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive"> </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>

                </div>
                }
                </div>
                @foreach (var item in Model.womanProductList)
        {
            <div class="col-md-4 single-right-left ">

                <div class="grid images_3_of_2">

                    <div class="flexslider">


                        <ul class="slides">

                            <li data-thumb="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageaFront)">
                                <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageaFront)" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive"> </div>
                            </li>
                            <li data-thumb="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageBack)">
                                <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageBack)" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive"> </div>
                            </li>
                            <li data-thumb="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageBack)">
                                <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageBack)" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive"> </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            
            }
        </div>
        <!--another two are same like above-->
                
                
<!--This is my Index.cshtml page..I just pass here Productid-->
<div class="tab1">
                   
                    @foreach (var item in Model.ProductList)
                    {
                        <div class="col-md-3 product-men">
                            <div class="men-pro-item simpleCart_shelfItem">
                                <div class="men-thumb-item">
                                    <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageaFront)" alt="" class="pro-image-front">
                                    <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageBack)" alt="" class="pro-image-back">
                                    <div class="men-cart-pro">
                                        <div class="inner-men-cart-pro">
                                            <a asp-page="/single" asp-route-id="@item.ProductID?tab1" class="link-product-add-cart">Quick View</a>
                                             

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="product-new-top">New</span>

                                </div>
                                <div class="item-info-product ">
                                    <h4><a href="single.html">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)</a></h4>
                                    <div class="info-product-price">
                                        <span class="item_price">$@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OriginalPrice)</span>
                                        <del>$@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FalsePrice)</del>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="snipcart-details top_brand_home_details item_add single-item hvr-outline-out button2">
                                        <form action="#" method="post">
                                            <fieldset>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="business" value=" " />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Formal Blue Shirt" />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="30.99" />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="discount_amount" value="1.00" />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="return" value=" " />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value=" " />
                                                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to cart" class="button" />
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
  <!--another three tabs are same like above with diferent list-->
  
  
  <!--This is my code behind file -->
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EliteShopping.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using RazorPagesDemo.Models;

namespace EliteShopping.Pages
{
    public class singleModel : PageModel
    {
       
        DatabaseContext _Context;
        public singleModel(DatabaseContext databasecontext)
        {
            _Context = databasecontext;
        }

        
        public List<Product> ProductList { get; set; }
        public List<woman> womanProductList { get; set; }
        public List<Footwere> FootwereList { get; set; }
        public List<Bag> BagList { get; set; }



        public void OnGet(int? id)
        {

            
           
           
            //for Men

            var men = (from ProductList in _Context.ProductTB
                       where ProductList.ProductID == id
                         select ProductList).ToList();

            ProductList = men;

           // for Bag

            var data2 = (from BagList in _Context.BagsTB
                         where BagList.ProductID == id
                         select BagList).ToList();

            BagList = data2;

           // for women

            var women = (from womanProductList in _Context.womanTB
                         where womanProductList.ProductID == id
                       select womanProductList).ToList();

            womanProductList = women;

            //for Footwere

            var Footwere = (from FootwereList in _Context.FootwereTB
                            where FootwereList.ProductID == id
                         select FootwereList).ToList();

            FootwereList = Footwere;

        }
    }
}
```

- Its a Asp.net core 2.0 Razor page application .
- The pages are connected to the  database,all are dinamic.

Answer (score 0):

In `index` page , the `Quick View` link is not passing the correct product id to the `single` page ,  you should passing the id /tab name like :

```
<a asp-page="/single" asp-route-id="@item.ProductID" asp-route-tab="tab1" class="link-product-add-cart">Quick View</a>
```

And then in single page , get the paramter like :

```
 public void OnGet(int id,string tab)
```

Comment: Excellent ...Thanks a lot .you have given me a great concept,aswm idea.....using this  finally I have solved my problem.  Now its working properly.Thanks ....Thanks...Thanks.

Comment: @UttamKumar , consider accept the reply as answer which may help others who meet same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

In index page I added

```html
<a asp-page="/single" asp-route-id="@item.ProductID" asp-route-tab="@item.tab" class="link-product-add-cart">Quick View</a>
```

And in single.cshtml.cs page I pass id/tab

```html
var data2 = (from BagList in _Context.BagsTB
                         where BagList.ProductID == id & BagList.tab == tab
                         select BagList).ToList();

            BagList = data2;
```

created one more property for every class same as following.

```html
 public string tab { get; set; }
```

Finally i added one more column to the data table name "tab" & insert the values.
Now its working properly as I aspected.

**So thanks to *Nan Yu* and  *Stackoverflow community***